# Merging a DataFrame across Rows while dropping the NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, data-manipulation

I have this data frame

[image: Data Frame Achieved]

I achieved this by writing this code

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Step Number' , 'CAN_Send' , 'CAN_Values'])
can = [{'ta1': ('atpcinfolamp_co', '3')}, {'ta2': ('xyz_signal', '4')}, {'ta2': ('abc_signal', '5')}]
keys = []
for can_signals in can:
    for key,value in can_signals.items():
        if key not in keys:
            keys.append(key)
            df = df.append({'Step Number' : key} , ignore_index = True)
            df = df.append({'CAN_Send' : value[0]} , ignore_index = True)
            df = df.append({'CAN_Values' : value[1]} , ignore_index = True)
        else:
            df = df.append({'CAN_Send' : value[0]} , ignore_index = True)
            df = df.append({'CAN_Values' : value[1]} , ignore_index = True)
df
```

I need to have a dataframe that looks something like this
[image: Required Output Dataframe]

**I am unable to crack how to merge across columns while dropping the NaNs at the same time.**

I tried something like

```
df = df.groupby('Step Number')[['CAN_Send' , 'CAN_Values']]
```

but this did not work as there are no numerical operations to convert the groupby object into a frame as I have string values and any methods to drop NaN ends up clearing my entire dataframe.

Any help in this regard is very much appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fill in the missing values of `Step Number` first by [`.ffill()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html). Then [`groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) `Step Number` and then [`aggregate()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) the remaining 2 columns with [`dropna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html), as follows:

```
df['Step Number'] = df['Step Number'].ffill()

df_out = (df.groupby('Step Number', as_index=False)
            .agg(lambda x: x.dropna(how='all'))
            .apply(pd.Series.explode)
         )
```

Result:

```
print(df_out)

  Step Number         CAN_Send CAN_Values
0         ta1  atpcinfolamp_co          3
1         ta2       xyz_signal          4
1         ta2       abc_signal          5
```

### Edit

For your new dataset, you can use the following codes.  It works also for the previous dataset and should work in general for the structures created by your program logics.

```
df['Step Number'] = df['Step Number'].ffill()
df['CAN_Send'] = df['CAN_Send'].ffill(limit=1)
df['CAN_Values'] = df['CAN_Values'].bfill(limit=1)
df = df.dropna().drop_duplicates()
```

#### Demo

**Data Preparation:**

Your codes are fine-tuned to make your logics work in general. Otherwise, if you have a key appear more than once but with other key appears in between this key (e.g. keys appear with sequence `ta1`, `ta2`, `ta1`), your existing logics will fail to add a new row for the `Step Number` of this key (e.g. the last `ta1`) which already exists in the list `keys`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Step Number' , 'CAN_Send' , 'CAN_Values'])
#can = [{'ta1': ('atpcinfolamp_co', '3')}, {'ta2': ('xyz_signal', '4')}, {'ta2': ('abc_signal', '5')}]
can = [{'ta1': ('atpcinfolamp_co', '3')}, {'ta1': ('hdcinfolamp_co', '5')}, {'ta2': ('xyz_signal', '4')}, {'ta2': ('abc_signal', '5')}] 
#keys = []
last_key = ''
for can_signals in can:
    for key,value in can_signals.items():
        if key != last_key:
#            keys.append(key)
            last_key = key
            df = df.append({'Step Number' : key} , ignore_index = True)
#            df = df.append({'CAN_Send' : value[0]} , ignore_index = True)
#            df = df.append({'CAN_Values' : value[1]} , ignore_index = True)
#        else:
#            df = df.append({'CAN_Send' : value[0]} , ignore_index = True)
#            df = df.append({'CAN_Values' : value[1]} , ignore_index = True)
        df = df.append({'CAN_Send' : value[0]} , ignore_index = True)
        df = df.append({'CAN_Values' : value[1]} , ignore_index = True)

df

  Step Number         CAN_Send CAN_Values
0         ta1              NaN        NaN
1         NaN  atpcinfolamp_co        NaN
2         NaN              NaN          3
3         NaN   hdcinfolamp_co        NaN
4         NaN              NaN          5
5         ta2              NaN        NaN
6         NaN       xyz_signal        NaN
7         NaN              NaN          4
8         NaN       abc_signal        NaN
9         NaN              NaN          5
```

**Run new codes:**

```
df['Step Number'] = df['Step Number'].ffill()
df['CAN_Send'] = df['CAN_Send'].ffill(limit=1)
df['CAN_Values'] = df['CAN_Values'].bfill(limit=1)
df = df.dropna().drop_duplicates()
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)

  Step Number         CAN_Send CAN_Values
1         ta1  atpcinfolamp_co          3
3         ta1   hdcinfolamp_co          5
6         ta2       xyz_signal          4
8         ta2       abc_signal          5
```

### Edit 2

Actually, for the structure of your source data `can`, you can directly arrive at your desired dataframe in a much simpler way as follows:

```
can = [{'ta1': ('atpcinfolamp_co', '3')}, {'ta1': ('hdcinfolamp_co', '5')}, {'ta2': ('xyz_signal', '4')}, {'ta2': ('abc_signal', '5')}] 

data = {'Step Number': [list(x.keys())[0] for x in can], 'CAN_Send': [list(x.values())[0][0] for x in can], 'CAN_Values': [list(x.values())[0][1] for x in can]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: This is working very well for me but just one issue. If I have multiple dictionaries with ta1 as key like : can = [{'ta1': ('atpcinfolamp_co', '3')}, {'ta1': (hdcinfolamp_co', '5')}, {'ta2': ('xyz_signal', '4')}, {'ta2': ('abc_signal', '5')}] then I am getting ValueError: Shape of passed values is (3, 3), indices imply (2, 3). No idea why this would be the case. This is not happening if I add more values dicts wit ta2 or ta3.

Comment: @TanmayLata See my edit above.  Note that I have fine-tuned your codes to make it works in general for keys inter-mixed with other key.  Feel free to let me know if any further question.

Comment: @TanmayLata  See my second edit for arriving at your target dataframe directly in a much simpler way.

Comment: thanks a lot, both the solutions are handling all my possible scenarios! great to learn from you!